flag = flag and dfs(i + x, j + y) evaluating differently from flag &= dfs(i + x, j + y)
Expected
The following four code snippets to evaluate the same:
a. flag = flag and dfs(i + x, y + j) 
b. flag &= dfs(i + x, y + j) 
c. flag = dfs(i + x, y + j) and flag
d.
res = dfs(i + x, y + j)
flag1 = flag and res

Result
a. does not evaluate correctly, however b, c, and d do.
Context
I was working on the leetcode problem Count Sub Islands and encountered a very odd Python behavior.
I had what I believed to be a working solution but no matter what I did, it would not run. Exasperated, I ChatGPT'd the answer, however, the ChatGPT answer was logically the same as mine but passed all test cases.
Tinkering around with it, I realized that I was setting a flag using flag = flag and dfs() which would result in an error, but ChatGPT had replaced the line with flag &= dfs().
I am returning booleans so this seemed logically the same to me. Flipping the order and setting a variable to equal the result of dfs will also end up with a correct solution.
Not sure what is causing this, anyone have an idea?
Code
def countSubIslands(grid1, grid2):
    for i in range(len(grid2)):
        for j in range(len(grid2[0])):
            if grid2[i][j] == 1 and grid1[i][j] == 1:
                grid2[i][j] += 1


    def dfs(i, j):
        if i < 0 or i >= len(grid2):
            return True

        if j < 0 or j >= len(grid2[0]):
            return True

        if grid2[i][j] == 0:
            return True

        if grid2[i][j] == 1:
            return False

        grid2[i][j] = 0

        flag = True
        flag1 = True

        dirs = [(1,0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]

        for d in dirs:
            x = d[0]
            y = d[1]

            # DOES NOT WORK
            flag = flag and dfs(i + x, y + j)

            # ALL THREE OF THESE WORK
            # a.
            # flag &= dfs(i + x, y + j)
            # b.
            # flag = dfs(i + x, y + j) and flag
            # c.
            # res = dfs(i + x, y + j)
            # flag1 = flag and res

        return flag

    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(grid2)):
        for j in range(len(grid2[0])):
            if grid2[i][j] == 2:
                flag = dfs(i, j)
                if flag:
                    counter += 1
                print('------------')

    return counter

grid1 = [[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1]]
grid2 = [[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]

countSubIslands(grid1, grid2)


This question is similar to: what is the difference between "&" and "and" in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@maciek97x hi, this problem is different from the difference between & and "and" in python. the issue pertains to flag = flag and dfs() not evaluating correctly due to dfs() not being fully run in the evaluation.
I believe the issue has to do with python's implementation of short circuiting / lazy evaluation.
If you carefully read my post, you will see the difference. Sorry if it is not concise enough, please let me know if you would want me to revise it.
I kept all of the context because I believed it to be important, this is not a surface level issue.

Given that you tagged your question with the correct term which is the answer ([tag:short-circuit-evaluation]), I am unsure what your actual question here is: you already seem to know the answer.

@KonradRudolph I was of the belief short circuit evaluation would only activate if the first term is False, however, if this was the case I would not be having a problem.
If the first term is False, it would be correct to short circuit, however I thought that if the first term was True, Python would wait for the second term to evaluate before setting a value to True.
Ex: flag = True and dfs() should wait for dfs to evaluate before evaluating flag
This is not the case.
If this is the intended behavior, a link to explain why this is intended would be appreciated.

@EdisonZhang You’re correct, the second term is only left unevaluated when flag is False. What makes you think this isn’t the case in your code?

It is inaccurate for you to say flag = flag and dfs() (is) not evaluating correctly.  Rather, you misunderstand how and works.  a and b evaluates to a if a is falsy, otherwise it evaluates to b.  If a is false, b is never touched.

I believe you both to be incorrect. Please try running my code and have one equal flag1 = flag1 and dfs(i + x, y + j) and flag2 &= dfs(i + x, y + j) and print them out when flag1 != flag2. Am I allowed to post a pastebin? Please carefully read my post. @KonradRudolph

Please try the code above with this added in. I chose option a but any of the other options result in the same issue. If the flag being False is short circuiting correctly it should always result in False. Hope this helps.
        for d in dirs:
            x = d[0]
            y = d[1]

            # DOES NOT WORK
            flag1 = flag1 and dfs(i + x, y + j)
            flag2 &= dfs(i + x, y + j)
        if flag1 != flag2:
            print("flag1 and flag2 are not equal")
            print(f"flag1 = {flag1}")
            print(f"flag2 = {flag2}")

@TimRoberts

I believe the form with short-circuiting and is not running the line grid2[i][j] = 0 for all the neighbors where the non-short-circuiting versions does. At any rate, you can easily verify what's going on by printing the board at each level of the DFS. I'm sure you'll find the short-circuiting is actually causing the search to behave differently.

@Gene This is correct, thank you. A short circuit results in a different DFS path which results in grid[i][j] not being ran at some point. I made my error in incorrectly believing that my DFS did not modify the board state.
